# Find the duplicate values of an array column in the dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have a dataframe with an array column like:

```
  val df = Seq(
  Array("abc", "abc", "null", "null"),
  Array("bcd", "bc", "bcd", "null"),
  Array("ijk", "abc", "bcd", "ijk")).toDF("col")
```

And looks like:

```
col:
["abc","abc","null","null"]
["bcd","bc","bcd","null"]
["ijk","abc","bcd","ijk"]
```

I am trying to get the duplicate value of each array in scala:

```
col_1:
['abc']
['bcd']
['ijk']
```

I tried to get the duplicate value in the list but no clue on how this can be done with array column

```
 val df = List("bcd", "bc", "bcd", "null")
 df.groupBy(identity).collect { case (x, List(_,_,_*)) => x }
```

Comment: You have to `explode` the array and then execute the `groupBy ` as you already did

Comment: Do you have spark 2.4?

Comment: Yes I am using Spark 2.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .withColumn("col", explode(col("col")))
  .groupBy("id", "col")
  .count()
  .filter(col("count") > 1 /*&& col("col") =!= "null"*/)
  .select("col")
  .show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use custom UDF

```
def findDuplicate = udf((in: Seq[String]) =>
  in.groupBy(identity)
    .filter(_._2.length > 1)
    .keys
    .toArray
)

df.withColumn("col_1", explode(findDuplicate($"col")))
  .show()
```

if you are willing to skip `null` values (as in your example) just add `.filterNot(_ == "null")` before `.groupBy`

Comment: I am getting an error when I run the dataframe in spark. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$findDuplicate$1: (array<string>) => array<string>)

Comment: If you are going to call `.groupBy` on the `in` arg, then `Seq[String]` might be the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate values of an array column could be obtained by assigning a monotonically increasing id to each array, exploding the array, and then window grouping by id and col.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  Array("abc", "abc", null, null),
  Array("bcd", "bc", "bcd", null),
  Array("ijk", "abc", "bcd", "ijk"))).toDF("col")
df.show(10)

val idfDF = df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id)
val explodeDF = idfDF.select(col("id"), explode(col("col")))

val countDF = explodeDF.groupBy("id", "col").count()

// Windows are partitions of id
val byId = Window.partitionBy("id")
val maxDF = countDF.withColumn("max", max("count") over byId)

val finalDf = maxDF.where("max == count").where("col is not null").select("col")
finalDf.show(10)

+---+
|col|
+---+
|abc|
|ijk|
|bcd| 
+---+
```